# Trying to get a timer to work with UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, timer, nstimer, nstimeinterval

My goal is to get my timer working with each UITableViewCell. Currently, I'm able to use a timer just fine with a normal ViewController when I set up the @objc method, and selector of that method. I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with my solution, and I believe that I can't use a selector outside of the current ViewController. I looked at comparable solutions to this problem on stack overflow, but the only solution they had was to create an array to store multiple timers. I don't want to store multiple timers, I just need to get reference to the individual property with the unique date and display that.

```
Class FavoritesTableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
 var timer = Timer()

 // MARK: TABLEVIEWS

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {     
     return favoriteArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "liveCell") as? liveActivitiesCell {
        Prop = favoriteArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(properties: prop)
        return cell
   }

               return UITableViewCell()
}
```

// TABLEVIEWCELL

```
class liveActivitiesCell: UITableViewCell {
 @IBOutlet weak var auctionEndsOnLabel: UILabel!

func configureCell(timerClass: timerClass, timer: inout Timer) {

 timerClass.getAuctionTime(beginDate: timerClass.beginDate, endDate: timerClass.endDate, _timer: timer, auctionEndsLabelFunc: auctionEndsOnLabel

    StartTimerFilter(timer: &timer)

}
 @objc func TimerFuncFilter(timerClass: timerClass, timer: Timer) {
    print("Timer\(timer)")
    timerClass.getAuctionTime(beginDate: timerClass.beginDate, endDate: timerClass.endDate, _timer: timer, auctionEndsLabelFunc: auctionEndsOnLabel)
}
func StartTimerFilter(timer: inout Timer) {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(liveActivitiesCell.TimerFuncFilter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    // DataService.instance.BothDatesReturnedTrue = false

}
```

Comment: What exactly are you using the timer for?

Comment: I have a list of properties that have a begin date and end date. I want to show the countdown until the end date. My timer works fine in a normal View Controller, so it's not an issue with that, just not understanding how to put it in a tableview.

Comment: one simple solution would be to call `reloadData()` after every second from the TableVC. This is not necessarily the best solution, but should work fine for your use case.

Comment: So whenever I run this method I currently have and a timer starts to update the label and tries to take the properties, it crashes. I wasn't sure how passing the timer is working out, or if it should be done this way.

Comment: So I see the `TimerFuncFilter` method should bet called after every 1 second. But, I am not sure what the `auctionEndsLabelFunc` argument is for.

Comment: It's just assigning the label.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164119/discussion-between-sam-and-bradford-gray).